# Difference between two keywords while using grep in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, shellcode

What is the output difference between these commands?

```
ps -ef | grep  \[t\]tyS1
```

and

```
ps -ef | grep ttyS1
```

Expected results is that previous will grep for `[t]tyS1` but is not actually happening.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: The first one will not match the `grep` command itself, the second one will. Because the string `[t]tyS1` doesn't match the regexp `[t]tyS1`.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2062/grep-why-do-brackets-in-grep-pattern-remove-the-grep-process-from-ps-results

Comment: [Quoting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). You want to match the string `[t]tyS1` literally, or you want to match `ttyS1` ?

Comment: Using a regex which doesn't match itself literally is a common trick to avoid having the search find itself in `ps` output.

Comment: You have to add the option -E to grep. "Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below)."

Answer (score -2):

Both commands looks for the same word: ttyS1, because the 'optional letters' that you put enclosed squared braquets contains only 't'.
If you want to search for the string: [t]tyS1, you should enclose your regular expression between quotes (" or ') to avoid shell substitutions, but I'm  not sure if it is your purpose.

```
ps -ef | grep  "\[t\]tyS1"
```

In the case that you want to search for ttyS1 OR ptyS1 the command would be:

```
ps -ef | grep '[pt]ty'
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: No, the backslashes serve the same purpose as quotes, you need to drop them if you add quotes and then the meaning is different.

Comment: If you would want to search for the [ itself, for example the process: "[kworker/3:0]", you need to use both quote and back slash